# How to send message to hotmail using asp.net without user password?

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp

I have a web page, In *CONTACT US* tab I have a forms user can only enter their Name, Email Id, Subject and message. Once they click the ok button I want to get those message to my hotmail account.

I tried some code. But it doesn't work.

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
smtp.Port = 587;
smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(txtUserEmail.text, txtPassword);
smtp.EnableSsl = true;

MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
msg.Subject = "Demo";
msg.Body = "Hi there..";

string toAddress = "xxx@hotmail.com"; // Add Recepient address
msg.To.Add(toAddress);

string fromAddress = "\"no reply \" <from@gmail.com>";
msg.From = new MailAddress(fromAddress);
msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

    try
    {
        smtp.Send(msg);
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
```

This code I tried. But it's having a password. I want user to send email without password to my xxx@hotmail.com

Here is my form design
[image]

Comment: That question **is very unclear** and the code does not make much sense. If a user contact you, then the email address will be embedded in the data and the user won't send a mail but form data to the server which will then send you an email. **Credentials and from address would be those of your email account on the server**. 
If you want user to send an email, then it would be through its client email program...

Answer (score 2):

That depends on your host. Usually web hosts give you a local SMTP server, then you can use it to send any mail you want, just need to know the configuration settings and use them with the SmtpClient.

If your host doesn't offer smtp (very strange unless you're selfhosting the page) you can:

1-Install a local SMTP server (if you manage the server), this is the preferred solution.

2-Use an external service like google to send the mails, but then you need to create an account on the service and use these credentials, and have in account that Google has a lot of restrictions sending emails (limit per second, marking mails as spam, etc etc).

Comment: User should no see the sender as data is sent to the server and the server send the email. If web browser send the email, then it would use client email program...

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you... the user is trying to send the email from the server (it's ASP .net as he stated on the question).

Comment: You might be better than me understanding poorly written question... I have probably written the comment at wrong location.

Answer (score 1):

Preferred way to do this is to not have the mail be sent from the users e-mail, but rather have a **dummy e-mail** that sends the mails and contains the data the user entered. Not the best solution probably, but it doesn't require user credentials.

Comment: ok tell me the way how to do. If you post sample code, that will be helpful, thanks

Comment: @mohamedfaisal There practically is no sample code for this. Create a new Gmail account (like `usercontact.yourcompany@gmail.com`) and use it's mail adress in `msg.From` and just set the credentials that you used to create the account.

Comment: In any event, you will need a password - you're right though in that you don't want to ask the user for their credentials. Use your own email account (either created on the company server or through Gmail or such) and send that way. Just remember that the user will see the email address you send from so it's best to use an account from your own corporate domain (donotreply@mycompany.com) -- that will look a lot more professional than x@gmail.com -- as far as samples, just google "send email c-sharp" and you're good to go!

Comment: @ShannonHolsinger - Is There no way directly to send an email to my account without user password?.. Is this the only way we can do it?.

Comment: The only without USER password is to use a different account. There are some SMTP servers that will allow you to send mail without any password whatsoever, but those servers are usually quickly overrun by SPAM bots and are of essentially no use. Besides, you want your email to look professional so it should come from an "@yourdomain" address, anyway. Seeting up an email account takes like 30 seconds. Talking about it here has taken longer than both setting up the address and coding the solution.